# Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I'm having issues with deserializing a nested array of JSON objects in c# using JavascriptDeserializer or NewtonJSON. I've looked everywhere on here and tried suggested fixes, but it keeps giving me this: 
**Edit** added full Response error

```
{
"Message": "Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array.",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer 
        serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList)  
    at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer 
        serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   
    at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer 
        serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   
    at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   
    at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, 
        IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   
    at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException"
```

}

The JSON it sends to the webservice ends up looking like this:

```
{
    "ProfileEntries": [
        {
            "TypeId": "C",
            "CodeId": "HEARTDZ ",
            "StudComment": "testComment"
        },
        {
            "TypeId": "C",
            "CodeId": "HIBLOOD "
        },
        {
            "TypeId": "F",
            "CodeId": "MARFANF ",
            "StudComment": "testComment"
        },
        {
            "TypeId": "F",
            "CodeId": "MITRALF "
        }
    ]
}
```

The reason you see some objects without "StudComment" is because I'm using knockout to save a value that is not originally part of the object when loaded.

My web service basically does this to get a list of the deserialized JSON **Edit** added method name

```
public void SaveProfileEntries(string ProfileEntries)
    {
        var healthInfoProfileEntries = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<HealthEntries>(ProfileEntries);
```

These are the classes I'm using to deserialize the data:

```
public class HealthEntries
{
    [JsonProperty("ProfileEntries")]
    public List<HealthEntry> ProfileEntries { get; set; }
}

public class HealthEntry
{
    [JsonProperty("TypeId")]
    public string TypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CodeId")]
    public string CodeId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("StudComment")]
    public string StudComment { get; set; }
}
```

It's confusing because when I test it using VS unit tests, it works perfectly, but when I'm using it in my website, it gives me the same InvalidOperationException

I've tried NewtonJSON with this method but it does not work either

```
var healthInfoProfileEntries = (HealthEntries)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ProfileEntries, typeof(HealthEntries));
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the name of the variable that contains the JSON string that you are passing into the Deserialize method, ProfileEntries?

Comment: Yes, I made sure it was the same or it would give me a parameters Error

Comment: Could you include the full error data in your question?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, thought I'd share for reference. I ended up getting rid of the classes to use for JSON deserialization (irrelevant step to fix this) but changed the parameters from single string to **array** of strings of the web service "Save" function to this

```
public void SaveHealthResponse(string[] profilesJson)
{
        var healthInfoProfileEntries = new List<HealthProfileEntry>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var profileJson in profilesJson)
            {
                var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HealthProfileEntry>(profileJson);
                healthInfoProfileEntries.Add(temp);
            }
        }  ...
```

this is how the JSON array is built on my client side (using knockout, but easily replacable with regular javascript):

```
 ko.utils.arrayForEach(selectedItems, function (item) {
                    serializedHealthInfo.push(ko.toJSON(item));
                });
 var dataJson = JSON.stringify({ profilesJson: serializedHealthInfo});

 $.ajax({
    data: dataJson,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: self.saveUrl
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `System.String` is not supported for deserialization of an array.
I was getting similar above error. Resolved with the following:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
MainCentre = jss.Deserialize<List<Centre>>(json);
```

Centre - class with subclass.
Deserialize works well, if the above class does not have subclass. To resolve class with subclass, I added the subclass as an array in the class.